# Why do I get "$digest already in progress" while using pure jquery mixed with $http call?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have this pattern (I know using pure jQuery is really bad, but I want to understand the issue):

```
$http.get('/api/my').then(function(){
  $('#item').find('input').focus(); //throws $digest already in progress
});
```

I can't imagine the `find` method doing any `$scope.$apply();` internally.
I don't have the issue when I comment or remove the line.

What is the reason?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's necessarily bad. But I do have to ask; what is changing with this call? I mean, surely you don't just *focus* on the `input` right?

Comment: I have strictly those lines, no more no less.

Comment: Okay, what else might be running at this point? What `$watch` commands might be leveraging the `$digest`? Do you have any `$emit` commands that are then changing something globally with the `$apply`?

Comment: I'm searching but nothing like this: no events or something else

Comment: Oh I have an idea of the reason, 2 seconds

Comment: Okay, I had a directive that wraps the call with a `$scope.$apply`. However, that does not explain why the `focus()` enters in conflict with the digest cycle.

Comment: $scope.$apply is (most of the time) evil, and suggest you're not programming the angular way. But hard to say what's wrong with such little code.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/m6xm7evw/ - can't reproduce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root cause.

In another directive:

```
inputElement.bind('focus', function () {
      childScope.$field.onFocus = true;
      childScope.$digest(); //oops...
});
```

No need to comment this code :)